# How to set jQuery breakpoints?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, breakpoints

Because this is my first post, so in the beginning welcome everyone.

Since I'm just starting in JS and jQuery, can someone suggest how to deal with jQuery breakpoints?

On the website, I have a menu at the top in `position: fixed` and `height: 200px`. In the menu linked to scroll to a specific section using jQuery. The selected section goes to the top of the page.

I have created breakpoints in CSS and e.g. below `1024px`, the menu is already `100px` hight. Do you have an idea on how to convert a rule in jQuery, so that below `1024px` scrolls to `top - 100`?

```
  <nav>
        <a class="region" href="#">Okolica</a>

    </nav>

 <section class="s1"> <section>
```

```
nav {
    height: 200px;

}

@media (max-width: 1024px) {

    nav {
        height: 100px;
    }
}
```

```
$('.region').on('click', function () {
    $('body, html').animate({
        scrollTop: $('.s1').offset().top - 200
    }, 2000)
})
```

I tried code below but it doesn't work.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init);
function init(){
let query = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 1024px)");
if(query.matches){
    $('.region').on('click', function () {
        $('body, html').animate({
            scrollTop: $('.s1').offset().top - 100
        }, 2000)
    })
}}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You just check the browser's `width()` or you can use `Math.max( document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth )`

Comment: I am a complete beginner with JS / jQ. How should I put this in the code? Where?

Comment: Put that Math.max line into a function, then just call the function and compare to your breakpoint width. Something like `if( myGetWidthFunction() < 1024 ) { .... }`

Answer (score 0):

you can extract the window size with vanilla javascript

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/innerWidth

```
window.innerWidth
```

Answer (score -1):

In jQuery you can write a breakpoint like this:

```
if ($(window).width() < 1024) {

    //YOUR FUNCTION FOR EXAMPLE
     $('.region').on('click', function () {
        $('body, html').animate({
            scrollTop: $('.s1').offset().top - 100
        }, 2000)
    })

  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much - it works!
Only at 1024 without px ;-)

Comment: And what do you think about a more universal solution, i.e. taking the height of the nav to a variable and subtracting it from top? I tried such a code, but unfortunately it did not work.

```
$('.region').on('click', function () {
    var menuHeight = $(nav).height();    
    $('body, html').animate({
        scrollTop: $('.s1').offset().top-menuHeight
    }, 2000)
})
```